# Jquery - index element starting from 1?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make index element start from 1 without using "if(index === 0) return true;"

```
$( 'h3' ).each(function( index ) {
        ...do stuff...
}
```

The reason a lot of loops start at 0 is because they're looping over arrays, and in most languages arrays start at index 0. How can I get it to start from 1?

Comment: use selector `:nth-child()` it starts from 1

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to skip the first element.

```
$('h3:gt(0)').each(function() {
    ...
});
```